# Pimpl idiom using shared_ptr working with incomplete types

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, pimpl-idiom

I'm reading Effective Modern C++ by Scott Meyers and he's discussing the use of the pimpl idiom and pointing to the implementation class with `unique_ptr`, but there is an issue of special member functions (such as destructors) requiring the type to be complete. This is because `unique_ptr`'s default deleter statically asserts whether the type to be deleted is complete, before `delete p` is used. So any special member functions of the class must be defined in the implementation file (rather than being compiler-generated), *after* the implementation class has been defined.

At the end of the chapter, he mentions there is no need to define special member functions in the implementation file if the smart pointer used is `shared_ptr`, and this stems from the way it supports a custom deleter. To quote:

> The difference in behavior between std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr for
>   pImpl pointers stems from the differing ways these smart pointers support custom
>   deleters. For std::unique_ptr, the type of the deleter is part of the type of the smart
>   pointer, and this makes it possible for compilers to generate smaller runtime data
>   structures and faster runtime code. A consequence of this greater efficiency is that
>   pointed-to types must be complete when compiler-generated special functions (e.g.,
>   destructors or move operations) are used. For std::shared_ptr, the type of the
>   deleter is not part of the type of the smart pointer. This necessitates larger runtime
>   data structures and somewhat slower code, but pointed-to types need not be complete
>   when compiler-generated special functions are employed.

Despite this, I still can't see why `shared_ptr` could still work without the class being complete. It seems like the only reason there is no compiler error when using `shared_ptr` is because there is no static assertion like `unique_ptr` had, and that undefined runtime behaviour could instead occur because of this lack of assertion.

I don't know the implementation of the `shared_ptr`'s destructor, but (from reading C++ Primer) I gathered the impression it works something like:

```
del ? del(p) : delete p;
```

Where `del` is a pointer or function object to the custom deleter. [Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) also makes it clear the `shared_ptr` destructor with no custom deleter uses `delete p`

> 3) Uses the delete-expression `delete ptr` if `T` is not an array type; .... **Y must be a complete type**. The delete expression must be well formed, have well-defined behavior and not throw any exceptions.

Emphasis on the fact that the deleted type must be complete. A minimal example of the pimpl idiom:

```
//widget.h

#ifndef WIDGET
#define WIDGET

#include <memory>

class Widget{
public:
    Widget();
private:
    struct Impl;
    std::shared_ptr<Impl> pImpl;

};

#endif // WIDGET

//widget.cpp

#include <string>
#include "Widget.h"

struct Widget::Impl{
    std::string name;
};

Widget::Widget(): pImpl(new Impl) {}

//main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "Widget.h"

int main(){
    Widget a;
}
```

When `Widget a` in `main.cpp` is compiled, the template of `shared_ptr` is instantited for type `Widget` (within `main.cpp`) and presumably the resulting compiled destructor for `shared_ptr` contains execution of the line `delete pImpl`, because I have not supplied a custom deletor. However at that point, `Impl` still has not been defined, yet the line `delete pImpl` is executed. This, surely, is undefined behaviour?

So how is it that when using the pimpl idiom with `shared_ptr`, I don't have to define the special member functions in the implementation file to avoid undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The deleter for a shared pointer is created here:

```
Widget::Widget(): pImpl(new Impl) {}
```

until that point, all the shared pointer has is the equivalent of a `std::funciton<void(Impl*)>`.

When you construct a `shared_ptr` with a `T*`, it writes a deleter and stores it in the `std::function` equivalent.  At that point the type must be complete.

So the only functions you have to define after `Impl` is fully defined are those that create a `pImpl` from a `T*` of some kind.

Comment: I see, so my assumption that the `shared_ptr` destructor calls `delete` directly (if no custom is supplied) was wrong, it still calls it through a function object. Thanks.

Comment: Although I have to ask to clear this up in my head, when you say the deleter is created "here", I assume this is done with a closure? I couldn't find details of the exact default deletor for `shared_ptr` (although I saw that `unique_ptr` uses `std::default_delete`).

Comment: @searg effects are specified, not implementation.

Comment: decouple the function's definition(in share_ptr's ctor) and usage(in shared_ptr's dctor) by introducing an additional deleter function object wrapper, this design choice must be for Pimp only. Good explanation! I wish Meyers could told the story as good as you did.